# python pandas DataFrame iterate through rows and compare two columns and apply function

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a DataFrame with two columns:

```
df:
ix             Col1   Col2
1               11.0  'JPY'
2               51.0  'EUR'

..
1000,000        27.0  'CAD'
```

I have a list of currencies `l1 = ['JPY','EUR',...,'CAD']`
I have a list of conversions `l2 = [5.0, 1.0, ..., 0.5]`

I have a function as well that I created:

```
def convert_currency(symbol, amount):
    index_value = list_of_symbols.index(symbol)
    rate = list_of_values[index_value]
    converted = amount * rate
    return converted
```

and I would like to apply this funcion as follows:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['currency'] != 'GBP':
        row['price_inc'] = convert_currency(row['currency'], row['price_inc'])
```

but it does not work.

what would be fast working solution to apply function to col1 values based on the col2 values and that function intakes col1 value and return value which replaces col1 values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you can use the following vectorized approach:

Source data sets:

```
In [108]: d1
Out[108]:
   ix  Col1 Col2
0   1  11.0  JPY
1   2  51.0  EUR
2   3  27.0  CAD

In [109]: l1 = ['JPY','EUR','CAD']

In [110]: l2 = [5.0, 1.0, 0.5]
```

Helper "exchange rate" Series:

```
In [111]: d2 = pd.Series(l2, l1)

In [112]: d2
Out[112]:
JPY    5.0
EUR    1.0
CAD    0.5
dtype: float64
```

Solution:

```
In [113]: d1.Col1 *= d1.Col2.map(d2)

In [114]: d1
Out[114]:
   ix  Col1 Col2
0   1  55.0  JPY
1   2  51.0  EUR
2   3  13.5  CAD
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand, but it seems you want to multiply your Col1 by some rate, which is different for different values of Col2. I would recommend doing this by using an "apply" function to create a new column called 'rate', which is the corresponding rate for each Col2 row. Then, multiplying Col1 by 'rate' is the solution. Here's some working code. I chose to store the mapping between Col2 and rate in a dictionary (whereas you do it in two lists), but the idea is the same.

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[11.0,'JPY'],[51.0,'EUR'],[27.0,'CAD']],columns=['Col1','Col2'])

mydict = {'JPY':5.0,'EUR':1.0,'CAD':0.5}

def get_rate(symbol):
    return mydict[symbol]

df['rate'] = df['Col2'].apply(get_rate)
df['price_inc'] = df['Col1'] * df['rate']


Out[87]:
Col1    Col2    rate    price_inc
0   11.0    JPY 5.0 55.0
1   51.0    EUR 1.0 51.0
2   27.0    CAD 0.5 13.5
```